# Expected number of targets hit with paired shooters

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation

Consider $n$ targets, with 2 shooters aiming at each target, as shown in the picture below. If we randomly choose $k$ out of the $2n$ shooters to fire, what is the expected number $E(k)$ of targets that will be hit?

[image]

I can of course solve this for simple cases and make some general observations, e.g.:

- Trivially $E(1)=1$, for any $n$.
- For $k=2$, fix one shooter, and the probability that the other
  randomly-chosen one is his 'partner' is $\frac{1}{2n-1}$, in which
  case one target is hit; otherwise, two targets are hit. From these
  probabilities the expectation easily follows.
- If $k>n$ then at least one target has both its shooters firing at it.
  Remove it and consider the problem with $n-1$ targets. Do this
  recursively until $k\leq n$. So the only uniquely interesting cases
  are $3 \leq k \leq n$.

I am wondering if this can be solved in the general case. The expectation will suffice for me, but of course the exact probability distribution would be even nicer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability that some target is hit, is $$1-\frac{\binom{2n-2}{k}}{\binom{2n}{k}}=1-\frac{(k-2n)(k-2n+1)}{2n(2n-1)}=\frac{k^2-4kn+k}{2n-4n^2}$$

The expected number of hit targest is $n$ times this probability.

So, $$E(X)=\frac{k^2-4kn+k}{2-4n}$$

It should be much more difficult to calculate the probabilities that
$m$ targets are hit.

Comment: @Henry As the two answers are basically identical, I'm accepting the first one. Thank you both, that's great.

Answer (score 4):

Concentrate on the first target.  The probability it is hit is $$1- \dfrac{{2n-2 \choose k}}{{2n \choose k}}= 1- \dfrac{(2n-k)(2n-k-1)}{(2n)(2n-1)}= \dfrac{k(4n-k-1)}{(2n)(2n-1)}.$$

By linearity of expectation, the expected number of targets hit is $n$ times this, i.e. $$\dfrac{ k(4n-k-1)}{4n-2}$$ giving $E[1]=1$ and $E[2n]=n$ as you might expect.

Comment: and also $E[2n-1]=n$ as you might expect